# Java- Parsing a large text file

Tags: java, parsing, text

I had a quick question. I'm working on a school project and I need to parse an extremely large text file. It's for a database class, so I need to get unique actor names from the file because actors will be a primary key in the mysql database. I've already written the parser and it works great, but at the time I forgot to remove the duplicates. So, I decided the easiest way would be to create an actors arraylist. (Using ArrayList ADT) Then use the contain() method to check if the actor name is in the arraylist before I print it to a new text file. If it is I do nothing, if it isn't I add it to the arraylist and print to the page. Now the program is running extremely slow. Before the arraylist, it took about 5 minutes. The old actor file was 180k without duplicates removed. Now its been running for 30 minutes and at 12k so far. (I'm expecting 100k-150k total this time.)

I left the size of the arraylist blank because I dont know how many actors are in the file, but at least 1-2 million. I was thinking of just putting 5 million in for its size and checking to see if it got them all after. (Simply check last arraylist index and if empty, it didnt run out of space.) Would this reduce time because the arraylist isnt redoubling constantly and recopying everything over? Is there another method which would be faster than this? I'm also concerned my computer might run out of memory before it completes. Any advice would be great.

(Also I did try running 'unique' command on the text file without success. The actor names print out 1 per line. (in one column) I was thinking maybe the command was wrong. How would you remove duplicates from a text file column in a windows or linux command prompt?) Thank you and sorry for the long post. I have a midterm tomorrow and starting to get stressed.

Comment: Use a Set instead of a List.  The contains of Set is much more efficient and will remove duplicates.  These days you need many GB to be really large.  I would call a TB extremely large, although even this is becoming more common. If you are worried that 5 million is too much, I suggest you calculate how much memory one million uses and estimate how much memory you will need.

Comment: you can only do 'unique' on elements after you sort them, and if your file size is less than a GB you should be done in a few minutes (or seconds depending on the amount of work you do with that data)

Comment: I'm still having a duplicate issue which doesnt make sense. So what the program is set up to do is read the procuders name, then I use producers.add(producername) to add the name to the HashSet. At the very end the program right before it terminates, I use an iterator to print the set out to the text file one at a time. I then went and tried loading it into the database and it still says it contains duplicate entries. This should be impossible. The file size with duplicates was 50k, after using HashSet and printing to the text file it came out to 7k. It seems like it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cost of lookup using arrayList contains() gives you roughly O(n) performance.
Doing this a million times is what I think, killing your program.

Use a HashSet implementation of Set. It will afford you theoretically constant time lookup and will automatically remove duplicates for you.

Comment: Thanks, I took everyone's advice. It was all basically the same. Seems to be running much faster now. The file size grew to about 12k in 3 minutes. It took about 45 minutes with arraylist. Its still going to take an hour, but that's fine. The text file is about 1 gb. It contains 800k+ movies. Each movie has keywords, actors,directors, year, time, rating, etc. I'm turning this large file into about 8 smaller ones. I finished them all a while ago except for directors, actors, and producers which contain duplcates. Set is working great, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use Set instead of List so you don't have to check if the collection contains the element. Set doesn't allow duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

-try using **memory mapped file** in java for faster access to the large file

-and instead of ArrayList use a **HashMap** collection where the key is the actor's name (or the hash code) this will improve a lot the speed since the look-up of a key in a HashMap is very fast